# Checking for spaces before/after a link element in XML using java parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I'm parsing an xml document in which there may be some lines that look like this:

```
<para>This is a sentence. Here is my<link>link</link>.</para>
```

I want to be able to check with my parser that there is always a space before and after the link elements, but not inside the tag itself, so that the XML looks like this:

```
<para>This is a sentence. Here is my <link>link</link> .</para>
```

Any ideas on how to check this?

Some notes:

- I am using both SAX and DOM to parse my documents
- I want it so that if there is no space in the appropriate place, my parser throws a warning

So far, this is all I have in my code:

```
public static void spacesForLinks(Node node, List<DocLintException> errors) {
    Node parent = node.getParentNode();
    String info = parent.getTextContent();
    boolean extraSpace = false;

    if (extraSpace) {
        int row = Integer.parseInt(node.getUserData(
                DocLintSAXParser.LINE_NUMBER_KEY_NAME).toString());
        int col = Integer.parseInt(node.getUserData(
                DocLintSAXParser.COL_NUMBER_KEY_NAME).toString());
        String systemID = node.getUserData(
                DocLintSAXParser.SYSTEM_ID_KEY_NAME).toString();
        DocLintException error = new DocLintException(
                row,
                col,
                systemID,
                "There should be spaces around the link element.",
                DocLintException.ErrorType.Warning);
        errors.add(error);
    }
}




}
```

Comment: Can you post any of your own code to start with?

Comment: I edited my post to add my starting code, damienc. Thanks for the help in advance.